# In an email beginning with 'Hello', should one put a vocative comma following the first word?

Tags: punctuation

Is it technically correct to write

> Hello, Bob,

It looks wrong to have a comma immediately after the first word, but given that "Hello" is very syntactically different from "Dear/My Dear", it seems that a vocative comma is required.  Is this seemingly wrong practice technically necessitated when beginning an e-mail with 'hello', 'hi', etc?

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

Of late, I've been striving to include the comma.  When I fail to do so, I feel as if I have wrongly punctuated the salutation.  Still, I suppose it is a matter of context. I'm a lawyer, and most often, my emails are written with formality.

If one is writing an email in a formal context, I believe the comma is appropriate.  In an informal context, the comma feels stilted.  There is a [Chicago Manual of Style Q&A note on this subject](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas/faq0008.html), and it suggests the same.

---

Also, I suppose it is worth making the allusion in your question explicit:  In *Dear John*, the word *Dear* is an adjective modifying *John*. In *My Friend*, the word *My* is a possessive pronoun modifying *Friend*.  But, in *Hello, John*, the word *Hello* is an interjection, not a modifier.

Comment: There _is_ a duplicate question, with a highly upvoted answer. However, ELU really values precedent, supporting references from a recognised authority. And your answer is the first to provide a reasonable link to a reasonable semi-authority (CMoS must surely edit even Q&A material). Happily, the previous answer agrees almost entirely with yours. // I usually choose to prioritise logic and style over complex rules (when clarity isn't an issue) when it comes to punctuation. I might use _Hello Bob – Just a quick text; I'm really in a mad rush today_ to match the activity level, **but**

Comment: _Hello, Bob ... I'm glad you've come to your senses and retired from teaching at long last._ to convey a hopefully shared tranquillity, with plenty of pauses to sit and chill. Omitting the comma can easily appear hectoring. Of course, these are informal examples. The overarching rule with _all_ formal writing (**are** emails ever formal?) when it comes to deciding in grey areas is 'What does the boss / editor / President / institution ... expect?' They should have a dedicated style guide (which may differ from that of the next nearest institution).